# Desktop application in a cloud

Tags: winforms, cloud

Is it possible to run desktop application (WinForms, MS SQL) in a cloud (e.g Azure)? Unfortunately we have legacy application which can't be rewriten in ASP or PHP but our customer doesn't have any infrastructure in his location (besides PC of course) and don't want to buy and maintain any server. Moreover the application needs web server (IIS) for some functions.

Comment: You might want to look into http://pinemango.com
It offer cloud desktop environments that can install regular desktop applications, and instantly "cloudify" them.
Note: It's also enabled with collaboration feature if desired.